# What is the purpose of the go_package_prefix in the buf build library?

Tags: go, buf

I I don't understand the purpose of the go_package_prefix code snippet in generating protobuf files

```
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
  go_package_prefix:
    default: github.com/imsobad/grpc-gateway-demo
    except:
      - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
plugins:
  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/go:v1.30.0
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
  - plugin: buf.build/grpc/go:v1.3.0
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
      - require_unimplemented_servers=false
  - plugin: grpc-gateway
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
      - generate_unbound_methods=true
```

I want to understand how the command "go_package_prefix" work

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested, according to the docs:
https://buf.build/docs/generate/managed-mode/
managed mode helps you, or other developers manage *.proto* files in your "buf" project, instead of managing them individually. The docs should explain that better than me though. So read that. Really. It is nicely documented.

However I can provide you with an example.

Lets say you have a *.proto* file, like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package v1.model;

message SomeMessage {
  string foo = 1;
  uint32 bar = 2;
}
```

Notice the package specification, and the lack of go_package option.

When using managed mode with default prefix, your *package* is essentially prefixed with your specified prefix option. E.g. you could simply specify `com.your.domain/project` as `go_package_prefix` default and then, all of your compiled proto potentially relying on these definitions will have `com.your.domain/project` as a prefix in their imports (no need to specify go_package for every individual protofile).

```golang
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// ...

import(
  // ...
  model "com.your.domain/project/v1/model"
  // instead of just being `model v1/model` which is usually not what you would want
  // ...
)
//
```

Hopefully, this explains some of the purpose behind the `go_package_prefix` option.

Note:
I am not a native speaker, so in case my wording or explanation is off-throwing, please feel free to correct me.